# git add -p not ignoring whitespace anymore

Tags: windows, git

Up until now I was able to do `git add -p` in my repo. Git would ask me for the hunks I'd like to add separately **ignoring all whitespace and/or line endings (crlf etc.)**

I now installed the most recent version of git for Windows (git version 2.7.1.windows.2) and for some reason, whitespace is not ignored anymore.

Whenever I `git add -p` now, the whole changed file is displayed (prefixed with minus signs in red, then again prefixed with plus signs in green), followed by the usual prompt

> Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?

So basically I'm not presented hunks anymore but complete files, making the feature pretty much useless.

What settings do I need to revert to/change to get "real" hunks again?

Edit: `git diff` has the same problem (as expected), `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` and `git diff --ignore-all-space` give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to reproduce the problem since I committed the files that weren't shown as hunks anymore.